# Big-O notation for Polynomial Time Complexity

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

Recently we had a quiz where one of the question were -

```
Q: Asymptotic notation for polynomial : 

 - 2^Ο(n)
 - Ο(n log n)
 - n^Ο(1)
 - None of these
```

I know that Polynomial time complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n^c)$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

But then I checked it up on Wikipedia, and it got me confused.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), Polynomial Time Complexity is $2^\mathcal{O(log n)} = poly(n)$, where  $poly(x) = x^\mathcal{O(1)}$.

---

So my questions are -

1. What is the $Big-O$ notation for ***Polynomial Time Complexity***
   and how is it $2^\mathcal{O(log n)} = poly(n)$ ?
2. What will be the answer for the quiz ? 
     <sub>I have answered *None of these* .</sub>

Also it has got this line - `In the table, poly(x) = x^O(1), i.e., polynomial in x.`

What does ***polynomial in x*** means ?

Comment: If $poly(x) = x^\mathcal{O(1)}$, then $poly(n) = n^\mathcal{O(1)}$ ?

Comment: @zkutch I think so. In any way, can those two be different ?

Answer (score 2):

The question is worded in a tricky way. When it says "polynomial" it really means "all functions that represent a polynomial complexity class". Essentially, they want the asymptotic notation for the functions $f(n)=1$, $f(n)=n$, $f(n)=n^2$, etc. The reason we want this is because you would see this inside big-O like $O(1)$, $O(n)$, $O(n^2)$, etc. Those functions represent these big-O sets.

The reason we talk about it this way is because we are talking about it in the world of complexity classes. An example is $P$.

\begin{align}
P = DTIME(poly(n)) = \bigcup\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}DTIME(n^k)
\end{align}

From the wiki on [DTIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTIME).

> If a problem of input size $n$ can be solved in $O(f(n))$, we have a complexity class $DTIME(f(n))$ (or $TIME(f(n))$).

So the asymptotic notation for the set of these functions is $n^{O(1)}$. The following is a way to reason about it.
\begin{align}
n^{O(1)} 
&= n^{\{0,1,2,...\}} \\
&= \{1,\ n,\ n^2,\ ...\}
\end{align}

To show that $2^{O(\log n)} = poly(n)$ is with the same reasoning as above.
\begin{align}
2^{O(\log{n})} 
&= 2^{\{0\cdot\log{n},\ 1\cdot\log{n},\ 2\cdot\log{n},\ ...\}} \\
&= 2^{\{0,\ \log(n^1),\ \log(n^2),\ ...\}} \\
&= \{2^0,\ 2^{\log(n)},\ 2^{\log(n^2)},\ ...\} \\
&= \{1,\ n^1,\ n^2,\ ...\} \\
&= n^{O(1)}
\end{align}

To formally show these are equal, you would have to use set notation.

Finally, "polynomial in x" means that $poly(x)$ grows polynomially depending on $x$. You can see that some of the entries in the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) have a function as the argument to $poly$. For instance, $poly(\log{n})$ (polylogarithmic) grows slower than $poly(n)$ (polynomial) since $O(\log{n}) < O(n)$.